# Streaming youtube via C sockets

Tags: c

I am designing a proxy server in C on linux platform and I am stuck that my server cannot stream youtube videos. Images (jpeg), text, links, flash, mp3 and files are working but you cannot stream youtube. It gives the error "an error has occured please try again later".
       Any suggestions on where I have missed. Do I have to make a UDP request(which will cause redesigning issue) ????

Comment: A bit of source code could help us to understand the issue...

Comment: I cannot show the entire 1000 line code but the crux is this line -
while((flag = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)
       {       
        printf("%s\n",buf);                 
        send(client,buf,flag,0);     
                memset(buf,0,flag);
       }
I am also storing the data in cache[not shown].

Comment: You definitely don't need UDP because web browsers don't do UDP.

Comment: "Who" (function) gives you the error? And "where" (variable) is it given?

Comment: Seth Carnegie: `send()` works just as well for TCP sockets as for UDP.

Comment: on youtube display screen. The youtube display screen continues to show sign of buffering and then terminates with the message that "an error has occured." On my side I can see that terminal screen is stuck and nothing is being loaded as if youtube cannot handle my request although what I am doing is to simply forward the request on clients behalf.

Comment: @duskwuff I don't see how that has to do with web browsers only using TCP.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice the "make a UDP request" bit. Never mind.

Comment: Youtube can send streams with RTSP, which allows video to be sent over RTP, which uses UDP. So, UDP support may be needed for all streams.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet:

```
while((flag = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    send(client,buf,flag,0);
}
```

`send()` is not guaranteed to send the entire buffer at once. You'll need to replace this with something like:

```
int count;
while((count = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0) {
    int offset = 0;
    while(offset < count) {
        int sent = send(client, buf + offset, count - offset, 0);
        if(sent <= 0) break;
        offset += sent;
    }
}
```

(Note that I've replaced `flag` with `count`.)

Comment: duskwuff I tried your solution but the problem still remains. Can you tell me whether this while loop will continue until all the data has been received ie continuously receiving or will it receive a small packet of data and then exit and again a new socket will open and it will receive other bytes. continuous vs discrete?

Comment: @Everyone : the problem is either with youtube or with special format videos. I tested it on other videos and it was working. metacafe and youtube are not working while most of the others are working. I dont find any reason why one is working while other is not.